# Cloudformation deploy aws sdk for javascript

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk-js

Looking at the AWS sdk for Javascript, it appears we can only `create stacks` but i'm looking of a way to `deploy` a stack. How would I do that with the provided sdk; this is what they currently have:

```
cloudformation.createStack(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I was hoping for something like this:

```
cloudformation.deployStack(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Basically, I would like to recreate this command using the sdk instead of the cli:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /path_to_template/template.json --stack-name my-new-stack --parameter-overrides Key1=Value1 Key2=Value2 --tags Key1=Value1 Key2=Value2
```

And this is because I use Linux and can put this in a shell script while most of the people I work with all use Windows and I don't want to use Windows Batch but instead a cross platform solution like npm and thus the `aws-sdk for javascript approach`.

How would you perform the `cloudformation.deployStack` using the `SDK` and `NOT` the CLI ?

Answer (score 9):

The current AWS sdk for Javascript does **not** currently have a deploy method, however, the AWS CLI's [deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) command is a wrapper:

> Deploys the specified AWS CloudFormation template by creating and then executing a change set

With that in mind, I wrote the following code:

```
const CloudformationInstance = new Cloudformation(accessParams)

CloudformationInstance.createChangeSet(changeSetParams, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err, err.stack)
  console.info('Succesfully created the ChangeSet: ', data)

  CloudformationInstance.waitFor('changeSetCreateComplete', {ChangeSetName: config.changeSetName}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err, err.stack)
  const { StackName } = data.Stacks[0]

    CloudformationInstance.executeChangeSet({ StackName, ChangeSetName }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw new Error(err, err.stack)
        console.info('Succesfully finished creating the set: ', data)
    })
  })
})
```

***Note:*** changeSetType(part of the changeSetParams) needs to be explicitly defined as ***either*** "Create or Update". So using something like:

```
const upsertParam = await CloudformationInstance.describeStacks(params, (err, data) => {
  if(err) return 'CREATE'
  return 'UPDATE'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!! A few notes are `waitFor` should be inside of callback of `createChangeSet`, otherwise, it gets 'Resource not in the stack' error. Also, `waitFor('changeCreateComplete')` should pass `ChangeSetName` as params instead of `StackName`.

Comment: @Emma Good call-outs, Updated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AWS.updateStack()` for updating resources only which is similar to sam deploy (in case a change occured it only updates the stack)